# Couch DB setup wizard ends prematurely

Tags: database, windows, installation, couchdb

I have downloaded CouchDB 3.1.1. I am trying to install the on Window 10 64 bit machine.
The following error occurs

[image: Installation Error]

Could anybody guide me on how to install couchdb in windows 10.

Comment: did you resolve this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Steps to follow to Install CouchDB**

1. Go to Start and type services and then click.
2. Go to windows installer
3. Restart the windows installer.(In case if it's not started then start windows installer)
4. Open CMD in administrative mode
5. msiexec /unreg
6. msiexec /regserver
7. regsvr32 vbscript.dll
   then click ok for the dialog box.

Retry to install the CouchDB.

Cheers!!!!

CouchDB is installed

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Install .Net 3.5 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=25150), run .Net installer as an Administrator, then re-run the CouchDB installtion.